# Rails ActiveRecord update_attributes problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am trying to run the update_attributes for a particular object, but everytime I try to run my script, I get the following error: `TypeError (can't convert String into Integer):`

Here is the code I am working with

```
media = Media.find(params[:media_id])
media.update_attributes({:started_encode => false, :encode_success => false, :akamai => false})
```

Any idea why this keeps throwing that error?

Comment: are they any callbacks on your Media model?

Comment: nope just a normal ActiveRecord Model

Comment: @DanSingerman - I feel like he has a before_* filter that is throwing this...

Answer (score 7):

Which are the names of the Media columns table?

You may have found this problem:

http://ethernetflow.blogspot.com/2010/11/rails-typeerror-cant-convert-string.html

Basicaly, you cannot have a column named "HASH" in your table.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string to a parameter that is expecting an integer, most likely in `params[:media_id]'. Try:

```
media = Media.find(params[:media_id].to_i)
...
```

Comment: The same as before, `TypeError (can't convert String into Integer):` and the error seems to be on the same line as the update_attributes call. If I run my code like `object.column = value`, then it works

Comment: can you provide a full stack trace in your answer with line numbers? I feel like the problem lies elsewhere...